# Why are the Polynomial Features used in a Linear Regression model not working as expected as the degree increases?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I'm fitting several polynomial regression models of varying degree. The smaller degree models (1 to 7) are behaving as expected. However, as the model increases in degree (8 or higher), the fitted curve flattens out.

I have the following questions:

  Why is it flattening out?

  What could be the reason behind this behavior?

Here's my code:

```
for deg in range(1, 15):
    a = PolynomialFeatures(degree=deg)
    regr_pol = make_pipeline(a, linear_model.LinearRegression())
    regr_pol.fit(data_x, data_y)
    plt.plot(data_x, data_y, '.')
    plt.plot(data_x, modelo.predict(data_x), '-')
    plt.show()
```

For `degree=7` it looks as expected:

[image]

but for a larger degree, e.g. `degree=14`, it flattens out:

[image]

Comment: Double-precision arithmetic buys you only about $16$ digits.  Those $16$ digits will distinguish $x=80$ from $x=80/(10^{16})^{1/14}\approx 6.$ You therefore haven't a prayer of connecting the behavior of the curve in the range $x\in[0,6]$ to its behavior near $x=80.$ This is one of many reasons why fitting high-degree polynomials (where "high" means greater than 2 or 3) is almost always a poor idea.